# Форматировать запрос Perl

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, консоль, perl

Сейчас имеется формат вывода tcpdump:

```
tcpdump -e -tt -nn tcp | perl -pe 's/(\d*\.\d*)\s.*length\s([0-9]*):\s((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\.(\d+)\s>\s((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\.(\d+).*/$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6/'
```

Он выводит данные в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все вроде бы здорово, но мне нужно записать эти данные в БД.
Есть концепция превратить все это в INSERT-запросы к MySQL такого типа:

```
INSERT INTO Table 
VALUES ('1586092251.654965', 120, '188.170.175.84', 22029, '192.168.132.251', 1194);
```

И так каждую строку.

Очень плохо разбираюсь в Perl, поэтому нужна помощь. Нужно отформатировать вывод строк в конкретные запросы к БД.

Направьте в нужное русло, как я мог бы это сделать, либо помогите исправить запрос.

Comment: Подставляйте нужные слова (типа "INSERT INTO TABLE") в правую часть оператора s/// (где $1 $2 $3 $4...). Но если уж в совсем правильное русло, то http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, если уж совсем правильно смотреть на это, то ответ надо искать в (готовых) инструментах типа https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/18601/sql-database-store.